# WCF : POST request refused (error 405) while GET is working

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I am trying to make POST/GET services using WCF. Where as I encounter no problem for GET, my POST service always gets error 405. I search on so many post but haven't found something to make it work. I just don't know what to try now.

Here is my contract :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;

using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DemoService
{
    #region Service contract
    [ServiceContract]
    [ServiceKnownType(typeof(DbElement))]
    public interface IDatabaseService
    {
        #region Services
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "description/{elementID}")]
        [Description("Get description of an element, identified in database by its Id")]
        DbElement GetElementDescription(string elementId);


        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                UriTemplate = "update/description/{Id}")]
        [Description("Update description of an element, using its id")]
        int UpdateElementName(string Id, DbElement Ident);
        #endregion
    }
    #endregion

    #region Service data
    [DataContract]
    public class DbElement
    {
        #region Properties
        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Order = 0)]
        public short SerialNumber { get; set; }
        #endregion

        internal DbElement()
        {
            SerialNumber = 0;
            Name = string.Empty;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

My web.config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>

    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true"/>
    </system.web>

    <!-- Following section is to be duplicated in exe app.config file (for the moment) -->
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service name="DemoService.DatabaseService" behaviorConfiguration="baseServiceBehavior">
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8666/1.0"/>
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
                <endpoint address="REST"
                          binding="webHttpBinding"
                          behaviorConfiguration="web"
                          bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingConfiguration"
                          contract="DemoService.IDatabaseService" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="webHttpBindingConfiguration" />
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="web">
                    <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" helpEnabled="true" />
                    <crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="baseServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <extensions>
            <behaviorExtensions>
                <add name="crossOriginResourceSharingBehavior"
                     type="DemoService.EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior, DemoService" />
            </behaviorExtensions>
        </extensions>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The Cors I use is as follow (inspired by https://enable-cors.org/server_wcf.html )

```
    public class CustomHeaderMessageInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> requiredHeaders;
        public CustomHeaderMessageInspector(Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            requiredHeaders = headers ?? new Dictionary<string, string>();
        }

        public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void BeforeSendReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            var httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;
            foreach (var item in requiredHeaders)
            {
                httpHeader.Headers.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }
        }
    }

    public class EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {

        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            var requiredHeaders = new Dictionary<string, string>();

            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Request-Methods", "POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS");
            requiredHeaders.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,Content-Type");

            endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(new CustomHeaderMessageInspector(requiredHeaders));
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {

        }

        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof(EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new EnableCrossOriginResourceSharingBehavior();
        }
    }
```

And my client for test is

```
<html></html>


<head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#jsonp2").click(function() {

      $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8666/1.0/REST/update/description/2",
        data: "SerialNumber=321,Name:hello",
        type: "POST",
        contentType:"application/json",
        crossDomain:true,
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8' },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          alert("Data from Server" + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("request failed: " + errorThrown);
        }
      });


    });
    $("#jsonp3").click(function() {

      $.ajax({
        url: " http://localhost:8666/1.0/REST/description/2",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
          alert("Data from Server" + JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert("request failed: " + errorThrown);
        }
      });


    });
  });


</script>
</head>

<body>
<button id="jsonp2" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Send X Post Request</button>
<button id="jsonp3" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Send X Get Request</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Calling the GET service works just fine.
Calling the POST service always return code 405 without reaching the entry point.

Couls anybody help me solve this problem ?
Thank you.

PS :
Here is the request header from the cient

```
Host :"localhost:8666"
User-Agent :"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0"
Accept :"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language :"fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3"
Accept-Encoding :"gzip, deflate"
Access-Control-Request-Method :"POST"
Access-Control-Request-Headers :"content-type"
Origin :"null"
DNT :"1"
Connection :"keep-alive"
```

and the answer header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headers :"X-Requested-With,Content-Type"
Access-Control-Allow-Origin :"*"
Access-Control-Request-Methods :"POST,GET,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS"
Allow :"POST"
Content-Length :"1721"
Content-Type :"text/html; charset=UTF-8"
Date :"Mon, 15 Jan 2018 08:28:17 GMT"
Server :"Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0"
```

I prepared a simple project to test my services : maybe it would make it easier for people to find out what's wrong with my implementation. Link to the project is [here](http://dropbox.com/s/ndbiscu2lzgkrmv/MyTestService.7z?dl=0)!

Thanks for any additionnal help

Comment: Your data isn't in json format. It should be something like: '{"SerialNumber": 321, "Name": "hello" }'

Comment: Thanks Fiddles for the help : following your point I try to avoid any mismatch between client and service side, ensure to make bodyStyle = Bare, etc... But still doesn't want  to work.
I prepare a simple project to test my services : maybe it would make it easier for people to find out what's wrong with my implementation.
Link to the project is : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndbiscu2lzgkrmv/MyTestService.7z?dl=0

Thanks for any additionnal help (I'm close to loose my mind with this problem)